# HTML can't change body background for some reason

Tags: html, css

Can't change the body background for some reason, here is how I am trying to change it:

```
body
{
    background-color:#066;
}
```

This should probably work, but for some reason it doesn't.

Comment: it works fine http://jsfiddle.net/zsjuj/

Comment: @user1305114 maybe you should post all the css...

Comment: @Jared Farrish - makes no difference, should work anyway

Comment: its not part of the code,just I habit of breaking a sentence will typing.Anyway I am using dreamweaver and don't think something wrong with the formatting or syntax ,something else is not letting me to change the BG

Comment: @MichalPlško - I was asking why it was there, not saying it would or wouldn't. I don't see a reason it should be there, do you? (and [my own test shows it should work](http://jsfiddle.net/LRkak/), exactly as posted, without knowing what the rest of the css is)

Comment: @Jared Farrish - I suppose he has more css to go there...

Comment: @MichalPlško - The OP stated it's only part of the question, not the css. Removed.

Comment: @Jared Farrish aah, had to read OP's comment 3 times to get it :) you're right... but anyway - it would work if it was part of the CSS too :)

Comment: I do have more css i can't put all css (or I don't know how to it says something to indent the code I am new to stack overflow)

Comment: I would use Firebug or Chrome Console to inspect the `body` tag and find out what is actually setting the background color. Either something later on or more specific is overriding it or obscuring it, or it's not being included somehow.

Comment: Have you tried setting the colour on `html` instead of `body`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
body
{
    background-color:#066 !important;
}
```

Comment: the important thing did work,but why do you think this was happening?

Comment: Selectors have weights, the important rule increases specificity and over rides another rule which is why you could not make the change you wanted.

Comment: Yeah I got that ,what I was wondering about is why wasn't it working before that.....